# What does 'got popped' mean exactly in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, slang

What does 'got popped' mean exactly in this context?

> I have your name on a $5,000 transfer via Western Union to a 9/11 hijacker. **And you got popped with 150 kilograms of high explosives in your house!**

(Film: Zero Dark Thirty - United States, 2012)

Answer (score 8):

To "get [popped](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/popped)" means to get *caught by the police*.

> 10. `Slang` To take into legal custody; arrest: *"Her friend was visiting and got popped for a DUI"*

Comment: It's an interesting usage in an American film. I always thought that to "get popped" was to be murdered by a hit man

Comment: @Andrew Wouldn't that be getting "offed" though? I do think "popped" in the slang sense has a lot of different meanings depending on context though. [This headline](http://www.military.com/daily-news/2012/08/29/ex-seal-ventura-got-popped-after-popping-off.html) for example: Ex-SEAL: Ventura Got Popped After Popping Off.

Comment: @ColleenV  Got *offed*, got *whacked*, got *hit*, etc.  Probably most of these were made up by Hollywood writers though, although apparently real gangsters started talking like the characters in *The Godfather* after the movie became popular.  Life imitates art.  :)

Comment: @Andrew I suppose it could be used that way, in the right context. But with the clarifying "got popped *with (contraband)*", it is taken to mean "caught by police with (contraband), which makes things worse for him" (or easier for the police).

Comment: @BradC  Yes, to be clear your answer is correct.  I just thought the slang meant something else.

Comment: @Andrew The meaning you're thinking about for _getting popped_ is to be shot with a gun.

Answer (score 4):

"Popped" is a street term for an encounter with law enforcement.  I can include many specific actions such as merely questioning to arrest or detainment.

I don't remember this specific dialog but it's clear form the context of Zero Dark 30 that the subject has at least been apprehended and is/was in custody of some agency.